# How to extract values from XML without hard coding names of elements using XQuery in SQL Server?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, xquery-sql

I have xml stored in a table and table with names/paths of the elements I am interested in.

I would like to extract values of these elements without hard coding paths and/or names of the elements. Structure of my xml will not change, it will always have parent/child/element.

Is it possible to join xml and table to get to the values of the elements?

Below is example of what I was able to get. I think it is possible to extend this solution to JOIN on ChildNode and Element but not sure how to use `.query()` and `.value()` to get to ChildNode and Element.

Thank you for your help.

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = 
'<Products>
    <RedProduct>
      <Details_RedProduct>
        <Width>1</Width>
        <Depth>2</Depth>
        <Weight>3</Weight>
      </Details_RedProduct>
    </RedProduct>
    <GreenProduct>
      <Details_GreenProduct>
        <Width>4</Width>
        <Depth>5</Depth>
        <Height>6</Height>
      </Details_GreenProduct>
      </GreenProduct>
    <BlueProduct>
      <Details_BlueProduct>
        <Width>7</Width>
        <Depth>8</Depth>
        <Lenght>9</Lenght>
      </Details_BlueProduct>
    </BlueProduct>
</Products>'

DECLARE @ProductElement table (ProductNode nvarchar(100), ChildNode nvarchar(100), Element nvarchar(20))
INSERT INTO @ProductElement SELECT 'RedProduct','','Width'
INSERT INTO @ProductElement SELECT 'GreenProduct','','Width'
INSERT INTO @ProductElement SELECT 'GreenProduct','','Height'
UPDATE @ProductElement SET ChildNode = 'Details_' + ProductNode

SELECT ProductsCollection.query('local-name(.)').value('.','nvarchar(100)') as TestOutput
FROM @xml.nodes('//Products/*') productsXml (ProductsCollection)
INNER JOIN @ProductElement el ON el.ProductNode = ProductsCollection.query('local-name(.)').value('.','nvarchar(100)')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sql:column()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191214.aspx) in your xquery expression and compare against `local-name(.)` to get the nodes you want.

```
select PE.ProductNode,
       PE.ChildNode,
       PE.Element,
       T.Col.value('.', 'int') as ElementValue
from @ProductElement as PE
  cross apply @xml.nodes('/Products/*[local-name(.) = sql:column("PE.ProductNode")]
                                   /*[local-name(.) = sql:column("PE.ChildNode")]
                                   /*[local-name(.) = sql:column("PE.Element")]') as T(Col)
```

Result:

```
ProductNode          ChildNode            Element              ElementValue
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ------------
RedProduct           Details_RedProduct   Width                1
GreenProduct         Details_GreenProduct Width                4
GreenProduct         Details_GreenProduct Height               6
```

**Edit:**
Another version that uses a join on fields instead. It *might* have a better performance for you depending on what your data looks like. The first version parses the XML for each row in @ProductElement and the second version shreds the XML and uses that to join against @ProductElement.

```
select PE.ProductNode,
       PE.ChildNode,
       PE.Element,
       X.ElementValue
from @ProductElement as PE
  inner join (
               select T1.Col.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') as ProductNode,
                      T2.Col.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') as ChildNode,
                      T3.Col.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)') as Element,
                      T3.Col.value('.',             'varchar(100)') as ElementValue
               from @xml.nodes('/Products/*') as T1(Col)
                 cross apply T1.Col.nodes('*') as T2(Col)
                 cross apply T2.Col.nodes('*') as T3(Col)
             ) as X
    on PE.ProductNode = X.ProductNode and
       PE.ChildNode = X.ChildNode and
       PE.Element = X.Element
```

Comment: Second option is slightly faster in my case.
Thank you very much for your answer and for providing two options.